# i wanna make gui for some function but it's not like what i want i am using python 2.7 and it's Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

**i want to put that second entry in down to drop down menu help me to fix this? i tried with place and pack but i don't know where i am doing mistake help me to fix this you can specify the function and how to use it like width and height position ?**

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *
network = Tk(className ="Network")
network.geometry('1000x600') # Size 200, 200
network.resizable(width=False,height=False)
svalue = StringVar() # defines the widget state as string
w = Entry(network,width=80,textvariable=svalue) # adds a textarea widget
w.pack(side=TOP and LEFT)
w.place(x=3,y=3)
button1 = Button(network,text="Press Me")
button1.pack()

# Add a grid
mainframe = Frame(network)
mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.place(x=10,y=30)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = StringVar(network)

# Dictionary with options
choices = { 'IP scanning','openport scanning','','Finding Emails based on domainname','OS footprinting'}
tkvar.set('IP scanning') # set the default option

popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)


button2=Button(mainframe, text="Choose any of them").grid(row = 1, column = 1)

popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)

# on change dropdown value
def change_dropdown(*args):
    print(tkvar.get())

# link function to change dropdown
tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)
T = Text(network, height=20,width=60)
T.grid(row=3,column=0)
T.pack()
T.insert(END,"Just a text widget\nin two lines\n")

network.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: if you run that gui there will be second white box side to the drop down menu and i want it to be downside of that drop down menu

Comment: You can place the Text area manually under the pop up box by `place`. You can do, `T.place(y = 85)`. There are a few errors in the code though you might want to look at

Comment: actually i don't understand that y and x in place can you explain it

Comment: forgotten that did work thankyou @R.p.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually place the text area `T` under the pop up box by using the `place` function. 
You give the x and  y co-ordinates a value to place it where you want on the GUI.

`T.place(y = 85)` will place it under the pop up box. You can also give an *x* value to it.

There are a few other errors in your code too, but I hope this was what you were looking for.